# Any 2 countable models of T have a Back-and-Forth system, then T is $\aleph_0$-categorical?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $\mathcal L$ a countable language.
Let $T$ a coherent $\mathcal L$-theory with no finite models.

Having the following definition of a Back-and-Forth system in mind:

> A Back-and-Forth system from $\mathcal A$ to $\mathcal B$ is a non-empty family of partial isomorphisms such that:
>
> (i) for every $\gamma \in \Gamma$ and $a \in A$ there exists an extension $\gamma '$ of $\gamma$ with $a \in dom(\gamma)$
>
> (ii) for every $\gamma \in \Gamma$ and $b \in B$ there exists an extension $\gamma '$ of $\gamma$ with $a \in im(\gamma)$

If any two countable models of $T$, $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ have a Back-and-Forth system $\Gamma$, how can one prove $T$ is then $\aleph_0$-categorical??

I've thought that, as $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ have a Bach-and-Forth system, one can get any partial isomorphism and finish constructing/extending a 'full' isomorphism between both universes i.e. $A$ and $B$. And as $\mathcal L, A, B$ are countable maybe the steps taken to construct said isomorphism are countable and somehow proving that $T$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical?

Anyways, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I strongly suspect there are typos in your definition of "Back-and-Forth" system.  I assume $\Gamma$ is intended to be the name of the system.  Clause (b) is probably intended to say $b \in \operatorname{image}(\gamma)$.

Comment: Do you understand what it means to prove that $T$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical?  From what you have said at the end it sounds like maybe you don't, so your first task would be to review the definition.

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't see any problems on that front.  If any two countable models have a back-and-forth system, and if the existence of a back-and-forth system between two countable models is enough to prove the existence of an isomorphism between the two models, then any two countable models are necessarily isomorphic to each other.

Comment: @RobertShore: The comment about "maybe the steps taken to construct said isomorphism are countable and somehow proving that $$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical" is nonsensical and suggests there is some serious lack of understanding of what they are trying to prove.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume the corrections noted in my comment above.

Since $\Gamma \neq \emptyset$, choose $\gamma \in \Gamma$ and define $\gamma_0 = \gamma$.  Let $a_n, b_n$ enumerate the elements of $A, B$ respectively.  Define $\gamma_{n+1}$ inductively as follows:

If $a_{n+1} \notin \operatorname{dom} (\gamma_n)$, choose $(\gamma_n)'$ to be an extension of $\gamma_n$ with $a_{n+1} \in \operatorname{dom}((\gamma_n)')$.  Otherwise, define $(\gamma_n)'=\gamma_n$.

If $b_{n+1} \notin \operatorname{image}((\gamma_n)'),$ choose $\gamma_{n+1}$ to be an extension of $(\gamma_n)'$ such that $b_{n+1} \in \operatorname{image}(\gamma_{n+1}).$  Otherwise, define $\gamma_{n+1} = (\gamma_n)'$.

Define $\gamma_\infty = \bigcup \gamma_n$.  This definition makes sense because $m \lt n \Rightarrow \gamma_n$ is an extension of $\gamma_m$.  By construction, $\operatorname{dom}(\gamma_\infty)=A$ and $\operatorname{image}(\gamma_\infty)=B.$  Then $\gamma_\infty:A \to B$ is an isomorphism.  Since, by assumption, any two countable models of $T$ have a back-and-forth system, we've now proved that any two countable models of $T$ have an isomorphism between them, and that means that $T$ is $\aleph_0-$categorical.